# Force push keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

In the IDEA 2017.3 I was able to do the force push in `Push Commits` window by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and then twice <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>. This doesn't work in 2018.1 anymore. What's the shortcut that I can use from now on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> to open push dropdown list and then use <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>.